# jquery looping and copying classes to parent

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, copy

I've got a lot of dynamically generated boxes.
Like this,

```
<div id="container">

<div class="element">
<div class="1"></div><div class="2"></div>
<div id="star"><div class="flexy threestar price100 city"></div>
<div class="3"></div><div class="4"></div>
</div>


<div class="element">
<div class="1"></div><div class="2"></div>
<div id="star"><div class="flexy fourstar price300 suburb"></div>
<div class="3"></div><div class="4"></div>
</div>


</div>
```

Now I am trying to loop through all boxes and  try to copy the .flexy to parent class .element

So I used

```
$( "div.flexy" ).each ( function( ){
$('.element').toggleClass($(this).attr('class'));

//alert( $('div.element').attr('class') );

} 
);
```

the copying works for the first time, after that I get double classes.
How to overcome this problem?
Result for .element should be sth. like

```
<div class="element flexy fourstar price300 suburb">
  <div class="1"></div><div class="2"></div>
    <div id="star"><div class="flexy fourstar price300 suburb"></div>
  <div class="3"></div><div class="4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try simply

```
$("div.flexy").each(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  $this.closest('.element').addClass($this.attr('class')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var num = 0;
$( "div.flexy" ).each ( function( ){

$('.element').eq(num).toggleClass($(this).attr('class'));
num++

} 
);
```

Or

```
$( "div.flexy" ).each ( function( ){

$(this).parent(".element").toggleClass($(this).attr('class'));

} 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the target for the copy is in the same section as the selection for next copy you'll get doubles next time around.

You can:

1. Copy to different section, not selected by the copy selection
2. Add a class to elements, and exclude thise in the copy selection